# Numbers: is it possible to add multiple select elements?

Tags: numbers

I'm working on template in Numbers. Some cell in template can have only specific values from code lists, so I decided to add pop-up format for them.

[image]

But some cell can have multiple values from code list, so what I need is to add multiple select box (where I can choose several values from dropdown list). Is it possible to do with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to make multiple selections from a dropdown list in Numbers.

One possible work around would be to use multiple columns.  Then use a formula to CONCATENATE the cells into a single string.  Not very elegant.

[Apple Support Community - Make a pop-up with multiple selections](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3285986?searchText=pop-up%20selection)